# Can all 4-order tensors represented by a matrix?

Tags: matrix-calculus, tensors

I am aware that some 4-order tensors can be represented by a matrix product for example: $I_2 \otimes I_2$.

Can all tensor represented by 2-order matrices and Kronecker Products?

My inital thought is no. But I want to find an elaborate explanation related to that.

Comment: Typical tensors will be indecomposable.

Comment: A fourth-order tensor can be flattened into a matrix, and any matrix can be decomposed as a sum of Kronecker products $$X = \sum_{k=1}^{r} A_k\otimes B_k$$ The number of terms in the expansion is determined by the value of $r$ which the rank of the matrix $X$ after it has been reshaped and its elements permuted. For further details, look for papers by vanLoan & Pitsianis. Better yet, search for Pitsianis' 1997 thesis, which contains Matlab code for the decomposition. Google the phrase _nearest Kronecker approximation_